# Comparing two integeres bu use of if condition in Python

Tags: python, if-statement

I have written below code and tried running in python, it works well if I give input as a =56 b = 67, but it gives wrong comparison if input given as a = 789,b =45566 -

Below is the code written

```
def max(a,b):
    if a>b:
        print(a+" is greater than "+b)

    else:
        print(b +" is greater than "+ a)

o1 = raw_input("Enter value of A ")
o2 = raw_input("Enter value of B ")

to = max(o1,o2)
```

---

Output is if A = 789 , B = 45566 is entered - 
Enter value of A 789
Enter value of B 45566
789 is greater than 45566

Comment: raw_input gives a string.

Comment: change `to = max(o1,o2)` to `to = max(int(o1),int(o2))`

Comment: make it your habit to check type of the variable using `type`.

Comment: And as a side note, you might want to choose a different name to your function, as it shadows the built-in `max` function.

Answer (score 2):

You're comparing strings. Just cast them to integers using the function `int` when calling `max`. Like that: `max(int(o1), int(o2))`.

Answer (score 2):

you are not comparing integers but string. Cast them to integers and you will have the result you want

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're reading strings from raw_input, and the comparison is a lexicographic one. So since '7' > '4', you get the result that '789' is greater than '45566'.

Have a look at this code to get some insight:

```
def max(a,b):
    if a>b:
        print(str(a) + " is greater than " + str(b))

    else:
        print(str(b) +" is greater than "+ str(a))

o1 = raw_input("Enter value of A ")
o2 = raw_input("Enter value of B ")
print type(o1)
print type(o2)
to = max(o1,o2)
o3 = int(o1)
o4 = int(o2)
print type(o3)
print type(o4)
to = max(o3, o4)
```

This is the output:

```
Enter value of A 789
Enter value of B 45566
<type 'str'>
<type 'str'>
789 is greater than 45566
<type 'int'>
<type 'int'>
45566 is greater than 789
```

Also, max() is a builtin in Python and by defining a function called max(), you're making it unaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
to = max(o1,o2)
```

to

```
to = max(int(o1), int(o2))
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want your input to be a integer you have to use :

```
o1 = input("Enter your first number : ")
```

Because raw_input is for a input of type string whereas input is for input of type integer

Comment: In python2, `input` is for accepting python statements or expressions, not just integers. `foo = input()` and then type things like `5==4` or `dict()` and it will work.  In python3, `input` works along the lines of python2's `raw_input`